# How to have more instances of marked js in one project?

Tags: javascript, javascript-marked

My problem, which I cannot overcome is that I cannot achieve a state where I have 2 parallel instances oh `markedjs` which work fully independently in terms of configuration I am passing through.

In other words I need two different markdown handlers, as in one case I want to parse markdowned text using say algorithm X, and the other using alghorithm Z. But from what I read in official docs it's... impossible...? Really?

> Calling marked.use() to override the same function multiple times will give priority to the version that was assigned last. Overriding functions can return false to fall back to the previous override in the sequence, or resume default behavior if all overrides return false. Returning any other value (including nothing) will prevent fallback behavior.

And indeed, that's how it works on my end - I use `marked.parse()` in two different parts of app and I see changes reflected in both places even though I try to conditionally change the configuration (using flag or something, doesn't matter, the result is always the same).

How to fix it? How can one develop such nonsensefull solution?

Comment: Have you tried importing it once and then assigning `marked` to `markedX`, and then importing again and assigning `marked` to `markedZ`?

Comment: @Pointy doesn't work. I either have X or Z options applied

Comment: Sounds like a question for https://github.com/markedjs/marked/issues, since this is an open source package, and if your use-case makes sense, the docs (and possibly the code) should probably address it.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I will ask there then

Comment: Well I have definitely been able to reassign the global `marked` to something else. Maybe you have to import it, reassign, unset the global `marked` symbol, then repeat that.

Comment: @Pointy but are you able to apply 2 different tokenizers or renderers and use them respectively in two different places in app and see 2 different outputs? Because I can't

Comment: @MateuszOsuch well what *exactly* have you tried along those lines?

Answer (score 0):

A little late on this answer.

To avoid this, you can instantiate a new `Marked` object and pass extensions to that, e.g.:

```js
import {Marked} from 'marked';

const renderer: RendererObject = {
  heading(text, level) {
    // turn headers into plain text
    return `<p>text</p>`;
  }
}
const marked = new Marked({renderer});
```

Documentation: https://marked.js.org/using_advanced#instance